# syncdb doesn't create tables for nested models

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a Django project with models of the following structure:

```
my_model/
├── __init__.py
├── models/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── my_model.py
    ├── my_other_model.py
```

my_model.py and my_other_model.py each containing a model, MyModel and MyOtherModel, and in my Django settings file I have added this folder to my installed apps list like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'my_model',
    ...
)
```

Now, when I run syncdb on my project I expect both models to generate a mysql table but MyModel is the only table created as mymodel_mymodel. I don't know how to make syncdb create the other model though as I expect to get another table called mymodel_myothermodel.

Thanks for your help,
Mattias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `django<=1.6`, [you must define `app_label` in your model's `Meta`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.app_label) for it to be picked up by syncdb if it does not live in `models.py`

Note that you're probably running `django<=1.6`, since `1.7` isn't out yet.

---

For `syncdb` to find the models, you'll likely also have to import them in `models/__init__.py`.

Comment: I have added app_label='my_model' to both class's Meta class but when I try to import the models from __init__ I get an import error when I import my_other_model because that one is trying to import my_model with the following error: import my_model.models. my_other_model, AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'models'

Comment: @materik You may have a circular import issue here. [Using a string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) in the ForeignKey's (or any other relationship) that you may have should fix the issue.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco do you know if there's a way to not have the imports in __init__ ? but still be able to syncdb ? I get circular imports everywhere that's causing me a lot of headache